# (scheme) How to substract lists of unary numbers?

Tags: list, scheme

i'm making a function that substracts two lists that contain unary number ( l l l = 3 or l l l l = 4)

So, it needs to do this:

```
~(usub '(l l l l) '(l l))
(l l)
```

Right now, i have a function that adds them up but not one that subtracts them. I figured it would be close to the add one but I can't figure it out. Help?

```
(define (uadd ls1 ls2)
  (if (null? ls1) ls2
    (cons (car ls1) (uadd (cdr ls1) ls2))))
```

Comment: `(make-list (- (length ls1) (length ls2)) 'l)` ?

Comment: @Ankur: The answer is still the same ;p http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=96 (was being slightly sarcastic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure to subtract it's very similar to the one that adds, the fundamental difference is that here we don't have to build a new list along the way, instead we'll return a sublist of the list we're subtracting from (`ls1` in this code):

```
 ; implements unary subtraction between two unary lists
 ; assuming that length(ls1) >= length(ls2)
 ; ls1: list we're subtracting from
 ; ls2: list we're subtracting
 ; returns ls1 - ls2
(define (usub ls1 ls2)
  (if <???>                ; is the list we're subtracting empty?
      <???>                ; then return the list we're subtracting from
      (usub <???> <???>))) ; advance the recursion
```

Clearly, the trick is knowing *how* to advance the recursion: notice that we're reducing the size of both lists until one of them runs out, at that point we return the other - that's how we subtract. For example:

```
(usub '(l l l l l) '(l l))
=> '(l l l)
```

Comment: I just made everything opposide of uadd (cons (car ls2) (usub ls1 (cdr ls2)) but its returning one 'l' less than it should be.

Comment: That won't work. For starters, no need to `cons` in here, we're "destroying" not "constructing" a list